# MOVE UPLOADED FILE no funciona

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema, quiero agregar imagenes a mi sistema por medio de un formulario, el siguiente corresponde a editar los campos de la base de datos. Me actualiza el link de la imagen en la base de datos pero no me la guarda en la carpeta de destino que necesito. Gracias de antemano.

```
<?php
// configuration
include('../connect.php');

// new data
$id = $_POST['memi'];
$a = $_POST['code'];
$z = $_POST['gen'];
$b = $_POST['name'];
$c = $_POST['exdate'];
$d = $_POST['price'];
$e = $_POST['kategori'];
$f = $_POST['qty'];
$g = $_POST['o_price'];
$h = $_POST['profit'];
$i = $_POST['date_arrival'];
$j = $_POST['sold'];
$nama_file = $_POST['namaFile'];

if (! empty($_FILES['namaFile']['tmp_name'])) {
        $nama_file = $_FILES['namaFile']['name'];
        $nama_file = stripslashes($nama_file);
        $nama_file = str_replace("'","",$nama_file);
        $nama_file = str_replace(" ","-",$nama_file);
        $nama_file = $a.".".$nama_file;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['namaFile']['tmp_name'], "images/".$nama_file);
        }
    else {

        echo "error";
    }
// query
$sql = "UPDATE products 
        SET product_code=?, gen_name=?, product_name=?, expiry_date=?, price=?,kd_kategori=?, qty=?, o_price=?, profit=?, date_arrival=?, qty_sold=?,file_gambar=?
    WHERE product_id=?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($a,$z,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$nama_file,$id));
header("location: products.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

La función move_uploaded_file() trata de mover un archivo que ya fue subido anteriormente, lo cual no es tu caso (estás subiéndolo ahora). Lo que debes hacer es utilizar copy():

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['nama_file ']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (copy($_FILES['nama_file ']['tmp_name'], $destino)) {
        // código para insertar en la base de datos
        // y cualquier otro procesamiento
    }
}
```

Aqui *destino* es el nombre del archivo como se almacenará en tu disco, incluyendo la ruta, por ejemplo:

```
$destino = ./folder_destino/$_FILES['nama_file ']['name'];
```

Además, el directorio de destino debe existir.